# How to activate right-click menu on Application Launcher list entries in KDE Plasma?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, launcher, context-menu

I've just started using Kubuntu with KDE Plasma.  In adding my frequently-used applications to the launcher bar, I noticed that there doesn't seem to be a way to do this using only the keyboard.

For example, I can pin the Dolphin file manager to the launcher bar using the following steps:

1. Press the OS (Windows) key.
2. Type "Dolphin."
3. **Right click on the result in the launcher menu.**
4. Press "P" for "Pin to Task Manager."

I want to do step 3 with the keyboard.  How can I do this?

I found instructions suggesting to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>, but neither of these worked.  Suggestions to use the "menu" button between the right <kbd>alt</kbd> key and the right <kbd>shift</kbd> key won't work either, because this Lenovo laptop has a "print screen" key in that position.  (Also, I usually plug in and use a CODE keyboard, which has a menu key - but I have it set to the "function" key option, which allows me to use the media key shortcuts built into the keyboard. So just finding the menu key on this one Lenovo keyboard wouldn't be a complete solution for me.)

Alternatively, I would like a way to pin applications to the launcher bar (task manager??) without using the mouse.  (Activating the right-click menu using the keyboard would accomplish that, but even if there's no way to do that there may still be a way to pin applications with the keyboard.)

Comment: Different Lenovo laptops have the "menu" button in different locations or invoke that with different keystroke combinations https://www.google.com/search?q=menu+button+Lenovo+laptop What is the model part number of your Lenovo? Please get that from the serial number sticker; other model numbers elsewhere on the PC are for markting purposes and don't help us find your HW manual at https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en

Comment: @K7AAY, is the "menu" key really the *only* way?  I usually plug in and use a CODE keyboard, which has a menu key - but I have it set to the "function" key option, which allows me to use the media key shortcuts built into the keyboard.  So just finding the menu key on this one Lenovo keyboard won't be a complete solution for me.

Comment: Good point! Please clarify your goal by clicking [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]